# How can I go about auto incrementing/refreshing time in Secnha

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a var of Wed Dec 09 2015 17:00:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I am getting this by making a network call in my controller file.

```
loadData:() {

    abstractNetworkCall(result){

        success:() {
            time = result

            displayTime(time)
        },
        fail { /*return error*/ }
    }
}

displayTime:(time) {
    this.setText(time)
}
```

I am looking to refresh the text field so it always increment.

Wed Dec 09 2015 17:00:27 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) for example

I have a long solution to how to this, is the a short what to do this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Why is your current solution unsatisfactory?

Comment: I can only display the time once...then the time is static. I am trying to auto increment it in real time on the screen

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow. Aren't you updating the time based on some remote request?

Comment: Right. Where setTime is, the time is going to be displayed to screen Wed Dec 09 2015 17:00:27 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Comment: I am interested to know how to update it in real time so it goes Wed Dec 09 2015 17:00:27 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) ->Wed Dec 09 2015 17:00:28 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) -> Wed Dec 09 2015 17:00:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Comment: i need it to keep refreshing and not to loop

Comment: Use `setInterval`. I don't see why you update it in the callback in the first place though. Is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

So I ended up finding a solution. setInterval for some reason just didn't work.

I used:

```
var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function(){ <update time>; 
task.delay(1000);
},this, time);//my variable time can be passed this way

task.delay(0);// this starts the interval
```